# Multiple input fields in edit text preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, edittextpreference

Is it possible to have multiple text input fields under single edit text preference and each input field to have its own key? I want to save phone numbers of 5 individuals and I don't want to create 5 separate edit text preferences for it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this design...

```
Individual 1:
     ###-###-####
Individual 2:
     ###-###-####

and so on...
```

Please look at the [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html) on making processes straight-forward and keeping context.